# how to get sha1 of android app in Vs code

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

how to get "Sha1" for a flutter application. I am using flutter in Vs code.In android studio we have direct option for that, but i don't know how to get it in Vs code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Change the directory to the JDK bin directory, mine was jdk1.7.0_05 (could be different for you).
   cd

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin
   ```
3. Next we have to run the keytool.exe. Use the following line to get the Android SHA1 fingerprint.
   Windows:

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore"-alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
   ```

   Mac and Linux:

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
   ```

Comment: @Frank  keytool.exe closes as we open it up is there any soltion for it....

Comment: how do you start keytool?

Comment: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/builder/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: I installed jdk; seems like no keytool is shipped in version > 8

Answer (score 84):

It's very simple follow below steps.

Step 1.  Go to your project directory in VS code.

Step 2.  Open terminal.

Step 3.  Run *cd android* for the below path :

Ex.: PS D:\Workspace\FlutterWorkSpace\FlutterApp\flutter_demo_app> ***cd android***

Step 4. Run *.\gradlew signingReport* for the below path :

PS D:\Workspace\FlutterWorkSpace\FlutterApp\flutter_demo_app\android> ***.\gradlew signingReport***

Then it will display like that

```
> Task :app:signingReport

Variant: debug

Config: debug

Store: C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore

Alias: AndroidDebugKey

MD5: 6C:64:D6:49:31:37:60:3F:1D:2E:31:2A:F4:3C:E3:D6

SHA1: 54:B0:BC:D6:D6:B4:C3:51:88:E9:20:62:56:CD:23:2D:A7:C0:0F:FD

SHA-256: 80:BF:B3:A8:0D:D6:D9:7C:C8:5F:61:32:22:6B:EA:D1:51:03:8D:1H:5E:0F:F7:0B:G3:56:1DD1:D1:3B:DB:FA

Valid until: Monday, 30 March, 2048
```

Comment: i dont have android or .android folder

Comment: Run ./gradlew signingReport for the below path : note the forward slash

Comment: I get this error `.\gradlew : The term '.\gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` any solution?

Comment: The code runs, everything is nice, EXCEPT, my VS code trims the output at the top. When i scroll up, the first value i see is > Task :firebase_auth:signingReport
Variant: debugAndroidTest. I can't f

Comment: i was tring `.\gradlew signingReport` and it didn't worked because of  \ . The correct one is `./gradlew signingReport`. Thank you @Rakesh

Answer (score 21):

open terminal - navigate to root project folder -

`cd android && ./gradlew app:signingReport`

PS: I tried the above code for my signed project

Answer (score 10):

Following these steps, that was the only steps that worked for me

1. Go to your VS project
2. Open the terminal
3. cd android
4. ./gradlew signingReport

That's all ;) your welcome!

Answer (score 8):

*In windows*

1. Open a terminal window
2. Run the following command by changing *USERNAME*

`keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

3. Simply get the SHA1

Answer (score 1):

in you project root

> cd android
>
> ./gradlew signingReport

Answer (score 0):

1 : open **cmd** in windows.

2: use  **cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin**  this will lead you to bin folder of jdk.

3:get path of file debug.keystore that in my case is  **C:\Users\name\.android\debug.keystore**

4: then run this command **keytool -list -v -keystore 
  C:\Users\name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android - 
  keypass android**

this will give you the **SHA1**

Answer (score 0):

in you project root

cd android

./gradlew signingReport

Answer (score -1):

1. open your terminal make sure you have selected the root folder of your project in that terminal
2. enter this command:- cd android
   E:\nitish\FLUTTER LEARNING\UI Design\login_app\android>
   3.enter this command :- .\gradlew signingReport
   and wait for some time...