# Unable to get the SHA-1 key through terminal

Tags: android, sha1

I tried to get my SHA-1 key by using the terminal but I don't know what problem is there, can anyone help me with this? I know how to get sha-1 key in android studio by signing report, but I want to generate in terminal.

Here is what I got when I run the command, I tried this answer but got nothing: [how to get sha1 of android app in Vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496090/how-to-get-sha1-of-android-app-in-vs-code)

[image]

above is my cmd. It is saying that it is an **illegal option**.

I have my Java bin directory here `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.2\bin` and  `debug.keystore` here: `C:\Users\91819\.android`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space between `"C:\Users\91819\.android\debug.keystore"` and `-alias`

Answer (score 0):

open the Project folder in VS code

Open the Terminal

Enter the following cmd and enter

> keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\yourusernamehere\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Replace yourusernamehere to your windows user name

you will get the SHA1 and other details.